# How to Check list containing NaN

Tags: python

In my for loop, my code generates a list like this one:

```
list([0.0,0.0]/sum([0.0,0.0]))
```

The loop generates all sort of other number vectors but it also generates `[nan,nan]`, and to avoid it I tried to put in a conditional to prevent it like the one below, but it doesn't return true.

```
nan in list([0.0,0.0]/sum([0.0,0.0]))
>>> False
```

Shouldn't it return true?

[image]

Libraries I've loaded:

```
import PerformanceAnalytics as perf
import DataAnalyticsHelpers
import DataHelpers as data
import OptimizationHelpers as optim
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime,date,time
import tradingWithPython as twp
import tradingWithPython.lib.yahooFinance as data_downloader # used to get data from yahoo finance
import pandas as pd # as always.
import numpy as np
import zipline as zp
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from itertools import product, combinations
import time
from math import isnan
```

Comment: This isn't a valid code - it should give an error because you can't divide list by float.

Comment: works on mine, and returns false. Anaconda 2.7.3 Python

Comment: Are you sure you see this before loading any libraries? Because in standard Python 2.7 this is an illegal operation. As well as NaN which could only come from some `from ... import *`. It may be the feature of your interpreter, so please add this information to the question.

Comment: In addition to my point, `numpy.nan in [numpy.nan, numpy.nan]` returns true as it should. I don't know where your nan comes from - I guess it is some library you are loading, because it is not a standard Python feature.

Comment: i understand what you mean and I agree. Do you see any libraries that i've loaded that causes this. The first 4 libraries are custom libraries and they themselves load the same thing.

Comment: OK, so, your `nan` comes from matplotlib.pylab (just as a note, never ever use from ... import * because you will get stuff confused between libraries very easily. It is considered bad practice). Again, for me it returns true in such case, as it should. I still don't get why did your list division worked though... Because it shouldn't work like this for ordinary list or numpy array.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think this makes sense because of your pulling `numpy` into scope indirectly via the star import.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [0.0,0.0]/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-aae9e30b3430>", line 1, in <module>
    [0.0,0.0]/0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

>>> [0.0,0.0]/np.float64(0)
array([ nan,  nan])
```

When you did

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
```

it pulled in `numpy.sum`:

```
>>> from matplotlib.pylab import *
>>> sum is np.sum
True
>>> [0.0,0.0]/sum([0.0, 0.0])
array([ nan,  nan])
```

You can test that **this** `nan` object (`nan` isn't unique in general) is in a list via identity, but if you try it in an `array` it seems to test via equality, and `nan != nan`:

```
>>> nan == nan
False
>>> nan == nan, nan is nan
(False, True)
>>> nan in [nan]
True
>>> nan in np.array([nan])
False
```

You could use `np.isnan`:

```
>>> np.isnan([nan, nan])
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.isnan([nan, nan]).any()
True
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [`math`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.isnan(item)
```

Comment: `math.isnan` expects a `float`, not an iterable. If you insist in using `math` you should do `any([math.isnan(x) for x in items])`. Note though that `numpy` should be much faster.

Comment: @Raf you were right. I was using bar charts with no bottom bar in the iteration that broke. I had to insert a white, hidden bar, save the SVG, then try again with the above code and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

May be this is what you are looking for...

```
a = [2,3,np.nan]
b = True if True in np.isnan(np.array(a)) else False
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR: best performance

##### (scroll down for graphs/charts of performance)

```py
has_nan = any(each!=each for each in your_list)
```

### Python NaN is more Weird than you think

```py
import math
my_nan = float("NaN")

list1 = [ math.nan ]
list2 = [ float("NaN") ]
list3 = [ my_nan ]

math.nan     in list1       # True
math.nan     in list2       # False
math.nan     in list3       # False

float("NaN") in list1       # False
float("NaN") in list2       # False
float("NaN") in list3       # False

my_nan       in list1       # False
my_nan       in list2       # False
my_nan       in list3       # True

# also makes sets really annoying:

set1 = set([math.nan    , math.nan    , math.nan     ])
set2 = set([my_nan      , float("nan"), my_nan       ])
set3 = set([float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan") ])

len(set1)   # >>> 1
len(set2)   # >>> 2
len(set3)   # >>> 3
```

For whatever reason, python treats NaN's similar to [JavaScripts symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

### Optimal Performance Answers

If your data is in a list/tuple/set this is the fastest way to check*

```py
has_nan = any(each!=each for each in your_list)
# from math import isnan #<- is slow
```

Okay so, that^ is the fastest way unless

1. You know that 99.9% of the time array wont have NaN (and/or 99.9% it will have NaN as the LAST element)
2. The list is *always* over 6000 elements
3. You really really really care about a 0.5% improvement
4. And you have numpy installed

Then this is slightly faster:

```py
# NOTE: can *average* 4x slower for small lists
has_nan = numpy.isnan(numpy.array(your_list)).any()
```

### ( Lower is better )

[image: perf_compare_1]

However, if the data is already inside a numpy array, then this is the fastest way:

```py
# when len() == 20,000 this is literally 100 times faster than the pure-python approach
has_nan = numpy.isnan(your_array).any()
```

[image: perf_compare_2]

Here's the performance/chart code (numpy 1.23 on python 3.11):

```py
import timeit
from math import isnan
import numpy
import random
from statistics import mean as average
import json


values = []
sample_size = 200
for index in range(1,15):
    list_size = 2**index
    source = list(range(0,list_size))
    cases = {
        "pure python: !=":[],
        "pure python: isnan":[],
        "numpy convert to array":[],
        "numpy (data already in array)":[],
    }
    pure_times = []
    numpy_times = []
    numpy_prebuilts = []
    for _ in range(0,sample_size):
        index = random.randint(-(list_size-1),list_size-1)
        local_source = list(source)
        if index >= 0:
            local_source[index] = float("NaN")
        local_source = tuple(local_source)
        prebuilt = numpy.array(local_source)
        
        cases["pure python: !="].append(timeit.timeit(lambda: any(each!=each for each in local_source  ), number=1_000))
        cases["pure python: isnan"].append(timeit.timeit(lambda: any(isnan(each) for each in local_source  ), number=1_000))
        cases["numpy convert to array"].append(timeit.timeit(lambda: numpy.isnan(numpy.array(local_source)).any(), number=1_000))
        cases["numpy (data already in array)"].append(timeit.timeit(lambda: numpy.isnan(prebuilt).any(), number=1_000))
    
    for each_key, each_value in cases.items():
        cases[each_key] = average(each_value)
    
    print(json.dumps({ "list_size":list_size, **cases,}))
    values.append({ "number of elements":list_size, **cases },)
    
# draw chart
import pandas
import plotly.express as px
df = pandas.DataFrame(values)
df = pandas.melt(df, value_vars=list(cases.keys()), id_vars=['number of elements'])
df["computation time"] = df["value"]
df.sort_values(by=["variable","number of elements"], inplace=True)
fig = px.line(df, color="variable",x="number of elements",y="computation time")
fig.update_layout(xaxis_type="log",yaxis_type="log")
fig.show()
```