# Why in numpy `nan == nan` is False while nan in [nan] is True?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

While the first part of the question (which is in the title) has been answered a few times before (i.e., [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)), I don't see why the second piece works the way it does (inspired by this question [How to Check list containing NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319813/how-to-check-list-containing-nan#comment30324111_20319813))?

Namely:

```
>> nan == nan
False

>> nan in [nan]
True
```

---

An explanatory addendum to the question considering the answer from @DSM. So, why `float("nan")` is behaving differently from `nan`? Shouldn't it evaluate again to simple `nan` and why interpreter behaves this way?

```
>> x = float("nan")
>> y = nan
>> x
nan
>> y
nan
>> x is nan, x is float("nan"), y is nan
(False, False, True)
```

Basically, it refers to same generic `nan` in the first case, but creates separate object in the second:

```
>> nans = [nan for i in range(2)]
>> map(id, nans)
[190459300, 190459300]
>> nans = [float("nan") for i in range(2)]
>> map(id, nans)
[190459300, 190459301]
```

Comment: Re your addendum, `float('nan')` always creates a new object. The `nan` that you're testing against is a pre-existing object that will never be the same ID as a newly created one. Assignment in Python always simply references the original object; `a = b; a is b` will always return `True` no matter what `b` is.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`nan` not being equal to `nan` is part of the definition of `nan`, so that part's easy.

As for `nan in [nan]` being True, that's because identity is tested before equality for containment in lists.  You're comparing the same two objects.

If you tried the same thing with two *different* `nan`s, you'd get False:

```
>>> nans = [float("nan") for i in range(2)]
>>> map(id, nans)
[190459300, 190459284]
>>> nans
[nan, nan]
>>> nans[0] is nans[1]
False
>>> nans[0] in nans
True
>>> nans[0] in nans[1:]
False
```

---

Your addendum doesn't really have much to do with  `nan`, that's simply how Python works.  Once you understand that `float("nan")` is under no obligation to return some nan singleton, and that `y = x` doesn't make a copy of `x` but instead binds the name `y` to the object named by `x`, there's nothing left to get.

Comment: Hmm... Why the nan's are the same in the first example? Why aren't they initialized as two different objects? Because `x = nan` and `nan in [x]` still returns `True`.

Comment: @sashkello: what first example are you referring to?  Your `nan == nan`?  `nan` names a particular object (in this case, I'm pretty sure it was the `np.nan`).  No matter how many times you say the name, it still refers to the same object: there's no initialization going on.  Similarly, `x = nan` doesn't make a copy of `nan`, it just makes `x` a new name and says that it names the object which is also named by `nan`.  Try `x is nan` after doing that, for example.

Comment: I just don't see how that is different from float("nan") then? Are there different 'flavors' of nan's? Otherwise, as I understand, float("nan") should still return nan which is again one same object, isn't it? I want to understand why `nan in [nan]` is different from `nan in [float("nan")]? How does interpreter know that the nan in the list has been obtained in a different way? I also don't get why float("nan") in [float("nan")] is false in such case...

Comment: No, as I said in the original question, nans aren't unique objects.  Look at the above transcript: the two `nan`s have different ids and `nans[0] is nans[1]` is False. `nan in [nan]` is True because it's basically `any(x is nan or x == nan for x in [nan])`.  `x is nan` is True so it doesn't matter that `x == nan` is False.  The same rule applied to `nan in [float("nan")]` gives `x is nan` is False (they're different objects) and `x == nan` is still False.  `float("nan") in [float("nan")]` gives False because they're TWO SEPARATE NANS.

Comment: OK, got it now. I just was thinking about nan as some sort of object value, while it is really object name...

Comment: @sashkello: yep, that's exactly it.

Comment: @sashkello, not that it matters much, but yes there actually *are* different flavors of NaNs, there are signalling NaNs too, which behave the same.