# Finding a string in pandas.Series using the IN operator

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I've the following pandas.Series:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,3,5,True,6,8,'findme', False])
```

I can use the `in` operator to find any of the integers or Booleans. Examples, the following all yield True:

```
1 in s
True in s
```

However, this fails when I do:

```
'findme' in s
```

My workaround is to use `pandas.Series.str` or to first convert the Series to a list and then use the `in` operator:

```
True in s.str.contains('findme')
s2 = s.tolist()
'findme' in s2
```

Any idea why I can't directly use the `in` operator to find a string in a Series?

Comment: `6 in pd.Series([1,2,6])` is False, so even numerical values are not working as you expect :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Any idea why I can't directly use the in operator to find a string in a Series?

Think of a Series more like an ordered dictionary than a list-- membership testing in a Series is of the *index* (like keys in a dictionary), not of the values.  You could access the values via under the `.values` attribute:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,3,5,True,6,8,'findme', False])
>>> 7 in s
True
>>> 7 in s.values
False
>>> 'findme' in s
False
>>> 'findme' in s.values
True
```

Comment: Interestingly, if I `import numpy as np` and then do `s = pd.Series([1,3,5,True,6,8,'findme', False, np.nan])`, I can't find the `NaN` by doing `np.nan in s.values` but I can find it by doing `np.nan in s.tolist()`. Thoughts?

Comment: @sedeh: `nan` is a weird one because `nan != nan`, so in general you can only get `nan in (something_which_contains_nan)` if it's IDENTICAL, and `tolist()` reuses `np.nan`.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true) for a previous answer of mine on nan-ish stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `Series.str.match()`.

```
s.str.match('findme').any()
```

Note this is doing a regex match, so it's very extensible. (If you don't need an exact match, you can use `Series.str.contains()`.)

`.any()` collapses the true-false series to a single value, as desired by the questioner.

Alternatively, you can use the more general method `Series.isin()` for exact matches.

```
s.isin(['findme']).any()
```

(Note that you have to wrap `'findme'` in brackets; `isin()` requires list-likes.)

In the comments, there was the question about finding np.NaN. The above code works for that example as well.

```
s = pd.Series([1,3,5,True,6,8,'findme', False, np.NaN])

s.isin([np.NaN]).any()
```

You can alternatively use the specific `Series.isna()` method, which is equivalent.

```
s.isna().any()
```

The advantage of `s.isin()` is that it's agnostic to datatypes if you're looking to match on multiple possibles:

```
s.isin(['findme', np.NaN]).any()
```