# The difference between comparison to np.nan and isnull()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nan

I supposed that

```py
data[data.agefm.isnull()]
```

and

```py
data[data.agefm == numpy.nan]
```

are equivalent. But no, the first truly returns rows where `agefm` is NaN, but the second returns an empty DataFrame. I thank that omitted values are always equal to `np.nan`, but it seems wrong.

`agefm` column has float64 dtype:

```
(Pdb) data.agefm.describe()
count    2079.000000
mean       20.686388
std         5.002383
min        10.000000
25%        17.000000
50%        20.000000
75%        23.000000
max        46.000000
Name: agefm, dtype: float64
```

What does `data[data.agefm == np.nan]` mean exactly?

Comment: Think you should be using `np.isnan`.

Comment: They are not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true

Comment: @Divakar So, if I should, is this a gap in *pandas* or I do a conceptual mistake?

Comment: Not really familiar with pandas isnull method, but we use np.isnan to detect NaNs with NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`np.nan` is not comparable to `np.nan`... directly.

```
np.nan == np.nan

False
```

While

```
np.isnan(np.nan)

True
```

Could also do

```
pd.isnull(np.nan)

True
```

---

***examples***
Filters nothing because nothing is equal to `np.nan`

```
s = pd.Series([1., np.nan, 2.])
s[s != np.nan]

0    1.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Filters out the null

```
s = pd.Series([1., np.nan, 2.])
s[s.notnull()]

0    1.0
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Use odd comparison behavior to get what we want anyway.  If `np.nan != np.nan` is `True` then

```
s = pd.Series([1., np.nan, 2.])
s[s == s]

0    1.0
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Just `dropna`

```
s = pd.Series([1., np.nan, 2.])
s.dropna()

0    1.0
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Are `np.isnan` and `pd.isnull` equivalent?

Comment: @sergzach no, but close.  I believe `pd.isnull` checks a few more things for null.

Comment: @sergzach Yes for `NaN`, not for `None`. You cannot use `np.isnan` for object arrays.

Comment: Your example is very good but may be not to use `s[s == s]` in practice? It seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

NaN is not equal to NaN; in fact, it's not equal to anything. It's implementation looks similar to the following.<sup>1</sup>

```py
class MyNaN(float):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'nan'
    
x = MyNaN()
print(x)        # nan
print(x == x)   # False
print(x != x)   # True
```

So, one possible way to check if there are NaN values is to check if a value doesn't equal itself. For example, if the aim is to find out which rows contain NaN, instead of checking for equality with NaN, check **in**equality with itself.

An example:

```py
s = pd.Series(['a', np.nan, 'b'])
x = s[s != s]
y = s[s.isnull()]

x.equals(y)       # True
```

###### `np.isnan` vs `pd.isnull`

`np.isnan` only works for numeric values, while `pd.isnull` works for all kinds of datatypes.

```py
s = pd.Series(['a', np.nan, 'b'])

s.isnull()        # OK
np.isnan(s)       # TypeError
```

<sup>1: Its actual CPython implementation is much more involved. This is only for illustration.</sup>