# Error: float object has no attribute notnull

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
  a     b     c
0 nan   Y     nan
1  23   N      3
2 nan   N      2
3  44   Y     nan
```

I wish to have this output:

```
  a     b     c      d
0 nan   Y     nan   nan
1  23   N      3     96
2 nan   N      2    nan
3  44   Y     nan    44
```

I wish to have a condition which is **when column a is null, then d will be null else if column b is N and column c is not null then column d is equal to column a * column c else column d equal column a**

I have done this code but i get the error:

```
def f4(row):
    if row['a']==np.nan:
       return np.nan
    elif row['b']=="N" & row(row['c'].notnull()):
       return row['a']*row['c']
    else:
       return row['a']

 DF['P1']=DF.apply(f4,axis=1)
```

can anyone help me point out where is my mistake? I have refer to this and try this but also get the error [Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition)

Comment: `row['c']` is giving you a *value*.

Comment: so any way to overcome this, because my row c should be contain nan(null value)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need `apply`, use `np.where`:

```
df['d'] = np.where(df.a.isnull(),
         np.nan,
         np.where((df.b == "N")&(~df.c.isnull()),
                  df.a*df.c,
                  df.a))
```

Output:

```
      a  b    c     d
0   NaN  Y  NaN   NaN
1  23.0  N  3.0  69.0
2   NaN  N  2.0   NaN
3  44.0  Y  NaN  44.0
```

Answer (score 26):

Use

```
pd.isnull(df['Description'][i])
```

or

```
pd.isna(df['Description'][i])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks, right this was too short, heres an add on:
For Series and DataFrame, the same type like ndarray of booleans is returned, containing booleans. So pd.notnull(df) and pd.notna(df) results the same.

Comment: Good solution, worked fine when I want to skip rows with NaN in iteration in a for loop: `for i, row in df.iterrows()` , `if pd.notnull(df['Column'][i]):`

Answer (score 7):

Since you just want `Nan`s to be propagated, multiplying the columns takes care of that for you:

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard()
>>> df
      a  b    c
0   NaN  Y  NaN
1  23.0  N  3.0
2   NaN  N  2.0
3  44.0  Y  NaN
>>> df.a * df.c
0     NaN
1    69.0
2     NaN
3     NaN
dtype: float64
>>>
```

If you want to do it on a condition, you can use `np.where` here instead of `.apply`. all you need is the following:

```
>>> df
      a  b    c
0   NaN  Y  NaN
1  23.0  N  3.0
2   NaN  N  2.0
3  44.0  Y  NaN
>>> np.where(df.b == 'N', df.a*df.c, df.a)
array([ nan,  69.,  nan,  44.])
```

This is the default behavior for most operations involving `Nan`. So, you can simply assign the result of the above:

```
>>> df['d'] = np.where(df.b == 'N', df.a*df.c, df.a)
>>> df
      a  b    c     d
0   NaN  Y  NaN   NaN
1  23.0  N  3.0  69.0
2   NaN  N  2.0   NaN
3  44.0  Y  NaN  44.0
>>>
```

Just to elaborate on what this:

```
np.where(df.b == 'N', df.a*df.c, df.a)
```

Is doing, you can think of it as "where df.b == 'N', give me the result of `df.a * df.c`, else, give me just `df.a`:

```
>>> np.where(df.b == 'N', df.a*df.c, df.a)
array([ nan,  69.,  nan,  44.])
```

Also note, if your dataframe were a little different:

```
>>> df
      a  b    c
0   NaN  Y  NaN
1  23.0  Y  3.0
2   NaN  N  2.0
3  44.0  Y  NaN
>>> df.loc[0,'a'] = 99
>>> df.loc[0, 'b']= 'N'
>>> df
      a  b    c
0  99.0  N  NaN
1  23.0  N  3.0
2   NaN  N  2.0
3  44.0  Y  NaN
```

Then the following would not be equivalent:

```
>>> np.where(df.b == 'N', df.a*df.c, df.a)
array([ nan,  69.,  nan,  44.])
>>> np.where((df.b == 'N') & (~df.c.isnull()), df.a*df.c, df.a)
array([ 99.,  69.,  nan,  44.])
```

So you might want to use the slightly more verbose:

```
>>> df['d'] = np.where((df.b == 'N') & (~df.c.isnull()), df.a*df.c, df.a)
>>> df
      a  b    c     d
0  99.0  N  NaN  99.0
1  23.0  N  3.0  69.0
2   NaN  N  2.0   NaN
3  44.0  Y  NaN  44.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
df['d'] = np.where((df.b == 'N') & (pd.notnull(df.c)), df.a*df.c, np.where(pd.notnull(df.a), df.a, np.nan))


    a       b   c      d
0   NaN     Y   NaN    NaN
1   23.0    N   3.0    69.0
2   NaN     N   2.0    NaN
3   44.0    Y   NaN    44.0
```

See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) for pandas notnull, in your current code, you just need to change series.notnull to pd.notnull(series) for it to work. Though np.where should be more efficient

```
def f4(row):
    if row['a']==np.nan:
        return np.nan
    elif (row['b']=="N") & (pd.notnull(row.c)):
        return row['a']*row['c']
    else:
        return row['a']
df['d']=df.apply(f4,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.isnull()` instead of `== np.nan`.

Example:

```
>>> x1 = np.nan
>>> x1 == np.nan
False
>>> pd.isnull(x1)
True
>>> pd.isna(x1)
True
```

Look this:

[The difference between comparison to np.nan and isnull()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342609/the-difference-between-comparison-to-np-nan-and-isnull)