# Error: 'float' object has no attribute 'isna'"

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below series:

```
my_series = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, ['A', 'B']])
```

I have to loop through my_series and evaluate whether the value is NaN or not and then do something (actions defined as 'do A' and 'do B' for the sake of simplicity).

**1st try:**

```
for element in my_series:
    if element.isna():
        print('do A')
    else:
        print('do B')
```

When running it, I've got the error: *"'float' object has no attribute 'isna'"*

**2nd try** from the question: [Error: float object has no attribute notnull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877663/error-float-object-has-no-attribute-notnull)

```
for element in my_series:
    np.where(element.isnull(), 'do A', 'do B')
```

When running it, I've got the error:  "*AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'*"

I haven't found any other similar question here at StackOverflow, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Try using `np.isnan()` in the second loop: `for element in my_series:
    np.where(np.isnan(element), 'do A', 'do B')`

Comment: Tried and got the following error:  " ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' "

Comment: Oops, then try `pd.isna()`: `for element in my_series: np.where(pd.isna(element), 'do A', 'do B')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for explicit for loops. Based on your second attempt:

```
# Setup
my_series = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, ['A', 'B']])

# Solution
np.where(my_series.isnull(), 'do A', 'do B')                                              

# Output
array(['do A', 'do A', 'do B'], dtype='<U4')
```

Answer (score 20):

Change your code to:

```
for element in my_series:
    if type(element) == float and pd.isna(element):
        print('do A')
    else:
        print('do B')
```

## Edit following the comment by *Peter*

I on purpose didn't change the original concept of processing the source
Series in a loop.
It looks like both print instructions are rather "placeholders", to be
replaced with one piece of code for *NaN* values and another for other values.

Comment: `pd.isna()` accepts any scalar or array-like object, not just floats. There is no need to check for `if type(element) == float`. Also, explicit for-looping over series values is slow.

Comment: Initially I tried as you suggested. But if the current element
is a **list** (as in the case of the last element), I got:
*ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*. This is why I added checking for *float* type.