# How to check if particular value (in cell) is NaN in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Let's say I have the following `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, np.nan, 2], "B": [5, 6, 0]})
```

Which would look like:

```
>>> df
     A  B
0  1.0  5
1  NaN  6
2  2.0  0
```

### First option

I know one way to check if a particular value is `NaN`:

```
>>> df.isnull().iloc[1,0]
True
```

But this checks the whole dataframe just to get one value, so I imagine it's wasteful.

### Second option (not working)

I thought below option, using `iloc`, would work as well, but it doesn't:

```
>>> df.iloc[1,0] == np.nan
False
```

However if I check that value I get:

```
>>> df.iloc[1,0]
nan
```

So, **why is the second option not working?** Is it possible to check for `NaN` values using `iloc`?

---

***Editor's note**: This question previously used `pd.np` instead of `np` and `.ix` in addition to `.iloc`, but since these no longer exist, they have been edited out to keep it short and clear.*

Comment: Explanation: try this: `pd.np.nan == pd.np.nan` ;)

Comment: That gives `False`! Why is that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true

Comment: That's the nature of "Not A Number". Because of that we have `pd.isnull()`, `pd.notnull()`, `IS (NOT) NULL` in SQL, etc

Comment: @ayhan, how do you think - should we close it as a dupe?

Comment: Aha, bingo. Hence using `is` would be a way to use `ix` or `iloc`?

Comment: @MaxU If the OP thinks that resolves it, sure.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, you better use `pd.isnull()` - it's a vectorized solution.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true answer your question?

Comment: Well, seems it doesn't. Although `pd.np.nan is pd.np.nan` resolves to `True`, `df.iloc[0,1] is pd.np.nan` still resolves to `False`

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, another hint: compare `type(pd.np.nan)` and `type(df.iloc[0,1])`. Don't use `is` for such checks

Comment: @MaxU, well, it answers a part of it. Actually after looking at that question I thouhgt `df.iloc[0,1] is pd.np.nan` would resolve to `True` but it's not. That question doesn't answer my second question. "Is it possible to check for NaN values using ix or iloc?"

Comment: Hence the answer for my second question is it's not possible? I know using `isnull` is the best and it will be the one I will use. But I still wonder why I cant use the second option (using `ix` or `iloc`) some way...

Comment: stop using `.ix`. STOP USING `.ix`!!!!

Comment: @TedPetrou, I guess in my case I can't as I'm stuck with `python 2.5` within the project I'm working with, due to using an external API dependent on `python 2.5`.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Try [pd.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html):

```
In [7]: pd.isna(df.iloc[1,0])
Out[7]: True
```

[AKA pd.isnull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086574/pandas-isna-and-isnull-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Great. That answers the second part of the question. I guess another way would be `pd.isnull(df).iloc[1][0]`

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, I like your original version (in the question) - `df.isnull().ix[1,0]` better

Comment: @Cedric also `np.isnan(df.iloc[1,0])` to check if a number is nan.

Comment: And I would add `df.iloc[1,0] is pd.np.nan` resolves to `False` as the types are not the same. `type(df.iloc[1,0])` resolves to `<type 'numpy.float64'>` and `type(pd.np.nan)` resolves to `<type 'float'>`, as suggested by @MaxU in question's comment, to check why this happens.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo and MaxU Isn't `pd.isnull(df).iloc[1][0]` far less efficient?

Comment: Opposite of `pd.isna()` is `pd.notna()`

Answer (score 14):

The above answer is excellent. Here is the same with an example for better understanding.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = pd.Series([np.nan, 34, 56])
>>> s
0     NaN
1    34.0
2    56.0
dtype: float64
>>> pd.isnull(s[0])
True
```

I also tried couple of times, the following trials did not work. Thanks to @MaxU.

```
>>> s[0]
nan
>>> s[0] == np.nan
False
>>> s[0] is np.nan
False
>>> s[0] == 'nan'
False
```

Answer (score 10):

`pd.isna(cell_value)` can be used to check if a given cell value is nan. Alternatively, `pd.notna(cell_value)` to check the opposite.

From source code of pandas:

```
def isna(obj):
    """
    Detect missing values for an array-like object.

    This function takes a scalar or array-like object and indicates
    whether values are missing (``NaN`` in numeric arrays, ``None`` or ``NaN``
    in object arrays, ``NaT`` in datetimelike).

    Parameters
    ----------
    obj : scalar or array-like
        Object to check for null or missing values.

    Returns
    -------
    bool or array-like of bool
        For scalar input, returns a scalar boolean.
        For array input, returns an array of boolean indicating whether each
        corresponding element is missing.

    See Also
    --------
    notna : Boolean inverse of pandas.isna.
    Series.isna : Detect missing values in a Series.
    DataFrame.isna : Detect missing values in a DataFrame.
    Index.isna : Detect missing values in an Index.

    Examples
    --------
    Scalar arguments (including strings) result in a scalar boolean.

    >>> pd.isna('dog')
    False

    >>> pd.isna(np.nan)
    True
```

Comment: Both functions `pd.isnull` and `pd.isna` do exactly the same. And actually `pd.isnull` is an alias of `pd.isna` as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086574/pandas-isna-and-isnull-what-is-the-difference).

Comment: Agree, for beginners, isna will be more readable while working with pandas.

Answer (score -1):

I made up some workaround:

```
x = [np.nan]

In [4]: x[0] == np.nan
Out[4]: False
```

but:

```
In [5]: np.nan in x
Out[5]: True
```

You can see list contain method [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cd44afc573e2e2de8d7e5a9119c347373066cd10/Objects/listobject.c#L427), to understand why it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.isnull().loc[1,0]
```

I tried the above syntax and it worked.

Comment: That might work for your case, but in OP's case, `.loc[1,0]` raises `KeyError: 0`. Maybe you meant `.iloc` instead, but then, doing `df.isnull()` on the whole dataframe is wasteful when you just want one value. I just updated the question to say that btw.