# Pandas isna() and isnull(), what is the difference?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has both `isna()` and `isnull()`. I usually use `isnull()` to detect missing values and have never met the case so that I had to use other than that.
So, when to use `isna()`?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`isnull` is an alias for `isna`. Literally in the [code source of pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py#L109):

```
isnull = isna
```

Indeed:

```
>>> pd.isnull
<function isna at 0x7fb4c5cefc80>
```

So I would recommend using `isna`.

Comment: Is there a recommendation which to use? Is one of them just legacy?

Comment: Since `isnull` is an alias for `isna`, I would tend to prefer `isna`. Indeed, `isna` seems to be used more often than `isnull`.

Comment: "There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it."

Comment: Presumably same would apply to `notna` and `notnull`?

Comment: Not only we should use `isna` for clarity, but `isnull` should also be deprecated. `isnull` which returns `False` for null values indicates some grass excess during design and quality review.

Comment: More explanation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html

Comment: I'm super annoyed that we have `np.nan` and `np.isnan()` but then pandas is `pd.isna()`

Comment: `pd.isnull` is not the same as `np.isnan`; `pd.isnull` (and `isna`) work on object dtypes, and return True for `None` so it makes sense to have a different name

Comment: `numpy.isnan` checks for NaN, which is "IEEE 754 floating point representation of Not a Number (NaN)." - paradoxically as it sound, NaN *is a number* - it is specific IEEE float constant saying "for whatever reason, i am not a regular number, i am Special"  - but in a bigger world where there are non-IEEE types like strings or dates, that is still number-ish. `isna()/isnull()` in contrast disavows any value in that cell, "it's vacuum here"

Comment: one more way of putting it, NaN is "numerical Null" and NA is "universal Null". i guess sometimes it matter, if someone decided to keep them different?

Comment: It's worth adding that ["DataFrame.isnull is an alias for DataFrame.isna"](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) and ["Series.isnull is an alias for Series.isna"](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html), though they're implemented as wrapper functions instead of plain aliases, I suppose so that the documentation can say exactly that they're aliases.

Answer (score 10):

They both are same. As a best practice, always prefer to use `isna()` over `isnull()`.

It is easy to remember what `isna()` is doing because when you look at numpy method `np.isnan()`, it checks `NaN` values. In pandas there are other similar method names like `dropna()`, `fillna()` that handles missing values and it always helps to remember easily.

Comment: `pd.isnull()`/`isna` has more functionality and different behaviour than `np.isnan`; it can also work on non-float datatypes, detect `None` and so on

Answer (score 8):

The documentation for both is literally identical.

[pandas.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html)

[pandas.isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html)

In here, it even says `DataFrame.isnull` is an alias of `isna` in "See also" section.

[pandas.DataFrame.isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html)

Therefore, they must be the same thing, like `np.nan`, `np.NaN`, `np.NAN`.