# Can I replace the null value of a cell in a dataframe if two conditions are satisfied?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nonetype

here we are!

Hi guys,
I am trying to write a loop where:
if the value of a cell in a specific column is 'None' and the value of the next cell is equal to an array of countries, then I change the 'None' value to the value of the next cell, that is the name of country.

I think I'm a bit off on solving this problem.

```
country_with_province = array(['Australia', 'China', 'France'], dtype=object)

for m in country_with_province:
    if df5.loc[(df5['Province/State'] == None) and (df5['Country/Region'] == m):
        df5.loc[:, "Province"] = df5.Province.fillna(m)
```

**INPUT:**

|  | Date | Province/State | Country/Region | Recovered | Province |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 22/01/2020 | None | Afghanistan | 0 | None |
| 1 | 22/01/2020 | None | Albania | 0 | None |
| 2 | 22/01/2020 | Tasmania | Australia | 0 | Tasmania |
| 3 | 22/01/2020 | None | Australia | 0 | None |
| 4 | 22/01/2020 | Hennan | China | 0 | Hennan |
| 5 | 22/01/2020 | Gansu | China | 0 | Gansu |
| 6 | 22/01/2020 | None | China | 0 | None |
| 7 | 22/01/2020 | Guineal French | France | 0 | Guineal French |
| 8 | 22/01/2020 | None | France | 0 | None |

**OUTPUT:**

|  | Date | Province/State | Country/Region | Recovered | Province |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 22/01/2020 | None | Afghanistan | 0 | None |
| 1 | 22/01/2020 | None | Albania | 0 | None |
| 2 | 22/01/2020 | Tasmania | Australia | 0 | Tasmania |
| 3 | 22/01/2020 | None | Australia | 0 | Australia |
| 4 | 22/01/2020 | Hennan | China | 0 | Hennan |
| 5 | 22/01/2020 | Gansu | China | 0 | Gansu |
| 6 | 22/01/2020 | None | China | 0 | China |
| 7 | 22/01/2020 | Guineal French | France | 0 | Guineal French |
| 8 | 22/01/2020 | None | France | 0 | France |

I working on a a df with 87552 rows.

Ty guys, I hope you can help me! I tried to search on stack, but I failed!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your method works fine, so... but you wanted something nicer

```
sel = df5['Province/State'].isnull() & df5['Country/Region'].isin(country_with_province)
df5.loc[sel, "Province"] = df5.loc[sel, 'Country/Region']
```

Comment: @ansev - I think It [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52628380/14277722)? Literally `pd.isnull is pd.isna` is `True`.