# How to pivot a specific dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe `df` with mixed data (float and text) which, when printed, looks like this (it's a very small part of the printing):

```
              0           1
0   Le Maurepas         NaN
1       CODE_90     AREA_HA
2           112      194.97
3           121       70.37
4           211      113.86
5    La Rolande         NaN
6       CODE_90     AREA_HA
7           112      176.52
8           211       97.28
```

If necessary, this output can be reproduced by the following code (for example):

```
import pandas as pd

fst_col = ['Le Maurepas', 'CODE_90', 112, 121, 211, 'La Rolande', 'CODE_90', 112, 211]
snd_col = ['NaN', 'AREA_HA', 194.97, 70.37, 113.86, 'NaN', 'AREA_HA', 176.52, 97.28]

df = pd.DataFrame({'0' : fst_col, '1' : snd_col})

df
```

I would like to give another structure to my dataframe `df` and get it to look like this when printed:

```
           Name     Code      Area
0   Le Maurepas      112    194.97
1   Le Maurepas      121     70.37
2   Le Maurepas      211    113.86
3    La Rolande      112    176.52
4    La Rolande      211     97.28
```

I browsed `SO` and I am aware that a function like `pivot(index='', columns='', values='')` could maybe do the job, but I don't know if it is applicable in my case, and, in fact, I don't know how to apply it...

Do I still have to insist with this function, by manipulating the parameters `index`, `columns`, `values`, or is there a particular way, corresponding more precisely to the structure of my initial dataframe `df`?

Any help welcome.

Comment: is there a pattern in the data? like 2 rows of text followed by 3 rows of numbers or is it mixed?

Comment: Yes, some kind of pattern: 2 rows of text followed by some rows of numbers, then 2 more rows of (different) text followed by some rows of numbers, and so on. The rows of numbers are in variable number.

Comment: @Andrew in your code to make the DF, you specify `'NaN'` (the **string**). Didn't you mean to use `np.nan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
#change the string "NaN" empty values
df["1"] = df["1"].replace("NaN", None)

output = pd.DataFrame()
output["Name"] = df.loc[df["1"].isnull(), "0"].reindex(df.index, method="ffill")
output["Code"] = pd.to_numeric(df["0"], errors="coerce")
output["Area"] = pd.to_numeric(df["1"], errors="coerce")
output = output.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output

          Name   Code    Area
0  Le Maurepas  112.0  194.97
1  Le Maurepas  121.0   70.37
2  Le Maurepas  211.0  113.86
3   La Rolande  112.0  176.52
4   La Rolande  211.0   96.28
```

Comment: I used your code (copy and paste) but, strangely, my `output` is void... some mishandling, maybe

Comment: @Andrew probably because the OP's code to make the df uses `'NaN'` (the string) instead of `np.nan`.

Comment: i get an empty df when using the example data and run this code

Comment: @not_speshal use `isna` instead of `isnull` ;)

Comment: even with `isna` I get an empty df. Is it a problem on my end ?

Comment: @Rabinzel see my above comment.

Comment: @Andrew - Edited. Just change the string "NaN" to actual empty values.

Comment: @richardec - Thanks for pointing out the input difference. `isnull` is fine though.

Comment: Yes, I replaced `NaN` by `np.nan`  in the piece of code outputting `df` and now it works!

Comment: @not_speshal I'm sure I read somewhere that `isna` is prefered to `isnull`...but anyway, while [`isnull` is an alias to `isna`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52628380), it seems better to use the original...

Comment: @not_speshal, actually, they are aliases. Check [the **latest** version of the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py#L146). Also, try `pd.Series(pd.NaT).isna()`. +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
indexes = (df[df['0'].eq('CODE_90')].index - 1).to_list()
indexes.append(len(df))
all_dfs = []
for idx in range(0, len(indexes)-1):
    df_temp = df.loc[indexes[idx]:indexes[idx+1]-1]
    print(df_temp)
    df_temp['Name'] = df_temp['0'].iloc[0]
    df_temp.rename(columns={'0': 'Code', '1': 'Area'}, inplace=True)
    all_dfs.append(df_temp.iloc[2:])

df = pd.concat(all_dfs, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```