# If statement on a specific cell in an Excel data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a specific line of script based on a cell value in an excel data frame. I basically want to conduct the calculation if a specific cell is not empty. For this, I used the code below:

```
check=df.iat[1,13]  #I am reading the value of the cell

if check is not (None, "[nan]"):
    print("cell is not empty")
```

when I print the value of check (the cell value), I get 'nan'. However, the if statement is not working as nothing is printed.

I am not sure why is this happening and I will appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Comment: change it to `if not pd.isna(check):`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440077/checking-if-particular-value-in-cell-is-nan-in-pandas-dataframe-not-working-us

Comment: cheers Vinzent, this actually works! I was not aware of the .insa, very helpful!

Comment: any idea why my script was not working?

Comment: could you please answer this question and I will accept the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by Vinzent

```
check=df.iat[1,13]  #I am reading the value of the cell
if not pd.isna(check):
    print("cell is not empty")
```

Comment: Is this not Vinzent answer? You could ask him/her to write the answer and you would accept it.