# filtering multiple criteria, including not nan

Tags: python

I am trying to get a subset of data from a `dataframe`, based on two criteria, where Region is like 'nebraska' and where metric1 is not `nan`

The region filter works, but the `nan` filter does not and I am unsure why. Would appreciate some pointers on why it does not work.

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
import pyodbc


data = [{ 'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':50},
        { 'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':50},
        { 'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':50},
        { 'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':50},
        { 'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':np.nan},]

testDataset = pd.DataFrame(data)

testDataset[(testDataset.Region.str.contains('nebraska')) & (testDataset.metric1 != np.nan)]
```

Comment: did the below solution help? feel free to accept if it did, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
testDataset[testDataset['Region'].str.contains('nebraska', regex=False, na=False) & \
            pd.notnull(testDataset['metric1'])]
```

`np.nan == np.nan` is `False` (see [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true)) which is why your method does not work.

I've also added `regex=False`, which should improve performance, and `na=False` so that you do not get errors for unexpected types.