# Weird null checking behaviour by pd.notnull

Tags: python, pandas, null

This is essentially a rehashing of the content of my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51035535/4909087).

I came across some weird behaviour when trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51035431/4909087), using `pd.notnull`.

Consider

```
x = ('A4', nan)
```

I want to check which of these items are null. Using `np.isnan` directly will throw a TypeError (but I've figured out how to solve that).

Using `pd.notnull` does not work.

```
>>> pd.notnull(x)
True
```

It treats the tuple as a single value (rather than an iterable of values). Furthermore, converting this to a list and then testing also gives an incorrect answer.

```
>>> pd.notnull(list(x))
array([ True,  True])
```

Since the second value is `nan`, the result I'm looking for should be `[True, False]`. It finally works when you pre-convert to a Series:

```
>>> pd.Series(x).notnull() 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

So, the solution is to Series-ify it and then test the values.

Along similar lines, another (admittedly roundabout) solution is to pre-convert to an `object` dtype numpy array, and `pd.notnull` or `np.isnan` will work directly:

```
>>> pd.notnull(np.array(x, dtype=object))
Out[151]: array([True,  False])
```

I imagine that `pd.notnull` directly converts `x` to a string array under the covers, rendering the NaN as a string "nan", so it is no longer a "null" value.

Is `pd.notnull` doing the same thing here? Or is there something else going on under the covers that I should be aware of?

**Notes**

```
In [156]: pd.__version__
Out[156]: '0.22.0'
```

Comment: What version of `pandas` do you use? In v. 23.0 `pd.notnull(list(x))` returns correct result: `array([ True,  False])`

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin 0.22. If this problem does not exist on 0.23, then it's certainly a bug that was fixed. Interesting.

Comment: Tested in `pandas 0.23.1` - `x = ('A4', np.nan)
print(pd.notnull(list(x)))` and return `[ True False]`

Comment: @coldspeed seems like this is the issue related to this behavior: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20675

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin perfect. That's the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin If you're upto it, write a few words as an answer and I'll be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the issue related to this behavior: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20675.

In short, if argument passed to `notnull` is of type `list`, internally it is converted to `np.array` with `np.asarray` method. This bug occured, because, if no `dtype` specified, numpy converts `np.nan` to `string`(which is not recognized by `pd.isnull` as null value):

```
a = ['A4', np.nan]
np.asarray(a)
# array(['A4', 'nan'], dtype='<U3')
```

This problem was fixed in version 0.23.0, by calling `np.asarray` with `dtype=object`.