# Any other suggestion to solving UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I get an UnboundLocalError: when using NaN in my if-statements. If I set NaN to 0 then the code works fine. However the code needs to work with NaN and not 0.

I've read most of the topics regarding UnboundLocalError: but I did't find what I was looking for.

```
import math
from math import nan as NaN
def interest(A, P, R, N):
    if R == NaN:
        val = (A/P)**(1/float(N))-1
    elif P == NaN:
        val = A/(1+R)**N
    elif A == NaN:
        val = P * (1 + R)**N
    elif N == NaN:
        val = (math.log(A)- math.log(P))/ math.log(1+R)
    return val

    print(interest(1000, 200, NaN, 5))
```

Comment: well, use "else" statement which will handle cases when if and elif's aren't fulfilled.

Comment: So what should happen if neither `R` nor `P` nor `A` nor `N` match `NaN`…?

Comment: Note that `math.nan == math.nan` returns `False`. Use `is math.nan` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments, your code is missing the logic to handle the case where none of the conditions evaluates to `True`.

Also `math.nan == math.nan` evaluates to `False` so your function call will never result in any of the `if` statements being `True` so `val` is never initialized which is why you get `UnboundLocalError`.

Have an `else` clause which should either return some appropriate value or just `None`.

Finally comparing `nan` to `nan` seemed redundant to me as in your function call the third argument passed is `NaN`.

This is just a slight modification to your code and it works.

```
import math
from math import nan


def interest(A, P, R, N):
    if R is nan:
        val = (A / P) ** (1 / float(N)) - 1
    elif P is nan:
        val = A / (1 + R) ** N
    elif A is nan:
        val = P * (1 + R) ** N
    elif N is nan:
        val = (math.log(A) - math.log(P)) / math.log(1 + R)
    else:
        val = None
    return val

print(interest(1000, 200, 'test', 5))
```

Comment: Well then yeah, but since `nan == nan` is False, having `== nan` in every condition seems completely redundant, imo.

Comment: It might be necessary since OP might want to check if each argument is NAN

Answer (score 0):

First, print statement in your code will never print anything due to wrong indentation, but I suppose you are aware of this.

Second, you get `UnboundLocalError`, because `val` is not assigned before it is returned. Interesting question is, why. The problem here is with `R == NaN` (and following), because by definition `NaN == NaN` is `False`. Therfore, `val` is never assigned. When you want to check, if some variable is `NaN`, you can use `R is NaN` or `R in [NaN]` (see [Why in numpy `nan == nan` is False while nan in [nan] is True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true)).

Just note, that using `else` (which is good manner generally) could give you a hint, what happened here.

Comment: Thanks for the intuitive explanation. much appreciated