# Using ffill() in a conditional np.where

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
       id    Apples     Values        1Y 
0       6  21973805     455215  21889611
1       4  36403870    5661698       nan
2       5    277500      98846       nan  
3       1        19        nan       nan
4       2       120       6466    568912
5       1      3210      86565       nan
```

And I want to fill the `nan` of `[1Y]` column with the previous known value. But I want to fill it ONLY if the corresponding `[Values]` value is not `nan`.

Thus getting the output:

```
       id    Apples     Values        1Y 
0       6  21973805     455215  21889611
1       4  36403870    5661698  21889611
2       5    277500      98846  21889611       
3       1        19        nan       nan
4       2       120       6466    568912
5       1      3210      86565    568912
```

I tried the following code:

`df['1Y'] = np.where((df['Values'] != np.nan) &  (df['1Y'] == np.nan), df['1Y'].ffill(), df['1Y'])`

But this changes nothing in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [pd.Series.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) to check for `nan` entries, if you do so:

```py
df['1Y'] = np.where((~df['values'].isna()) & (df['1Y'].isna()), 
                    df['1Y'].ffill(), df['1Y'])

df['1Y']
0    21889611.0
1    21889611.0
2    21889611.0
3           NaN
4      568912.0
5      568912.0
Name: 1Y, dtype: float64
```

If fact `np.nan==np.nan` return `False`, check more here: [why np.nan != np.nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true).