# nan in float64 detection problem in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, nan

I have problem by detecting 'nan' in pandas dataframe if column is float64 data type. Both comparsion operators ('nan' == for 'nan', 'NaN', np.nan) and functions sucha as .isnull() do not work.

Moreover this making me crazy:

```
np.float64(np.nan) == np.float64(np.nan)

out: False
```

Can anyone explain that issue?

Comment: Related: [Why NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10034149/12416453)

Comment: Another related: [Why `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20320022/12416453)

Comment: From [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html) `np.nan == np.nan  # is always False! Use special numpy functions instead`

Comment: Following above comments, `pd.isna()` is also useful, especially for Pandas objects (dataframes and series).

Comment: just need to use logic / philosophy.  Are the things you don't know the same as the things I don't know.  They are not,  therefore in general case unknown is is not equal to another unknown. Similar to in mathematics infinite is not the same as any infinite