# Fill values in pandas column with condition involving 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to fill this 'C' column in such a way that when the value in 'A' is not NaN, 'C' takes value from 'B', else the value in 'C' remains unchanged.

Heres the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['greek', 'indian', np.nan, np.nan, 'australian'], 'B': 
     np.random.random(5)})
df['C'] = np.nan

df
```

I tried `df.C = df.B.where(df.A != np.nan, np.nan)`, but it isnt working as the condition involves another column i think, for loop isnt yielding the desired result either.
How to get there using shortest lines of codes as possible?

Comment: `df["C"] = df[~df["A"].isna()]["B"]`?

Comment: `~df["A"].isna()` can be replaced by `df["A"].notna()` @not_speshal

Comment: @not_speshal It works! But can you explain it please?

Comment: @ThePyGuy, thanks, is it not possible to get there using np.where?

Comment: `nan` does not equal `nan` by definition. `print(np.nan != np.nan)  # True` Which is why comparing to NaN does not work. [Why in numpy `nan == nan` is False while nan in nan is True?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20320022/15497888)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `np.where`, the problem is that you are comparing the value directly against `np.nan` using `!=`

```py
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

So, use a function/method that allows you to check if the value is `nan` or not:

```py
>>> df.C = df.B.where(df.A.notna(), np.nan)

            A         B         C
0       greek  0.030809  0.030809
1      indian  0.545261  0.545261
2         NaN  0.470802       NaN
3         NaN  0.716640       NaN
4  australian  0.148297  0.148297
```