# How to get logical mask of two lists if lists contain np.NaN

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, logical-operators

Logical OR and logical AND seems do not work when list have np.NaN. I produced simple example:
If I will have ndarray filled with np.NaN, it do not work correctly:

```
import numpy as np
m =10
l1, l2 = np.array([np.NaN] * m), np.array([np.NaN] * m)
l1[3] = 5
l2[3] = 5
l1[5] = 6
l2[5] = 6
l2[7] = 7
l1[8] = 8

mask1 = (l1 != np.NaN) & (l2 != np.NaN)
mask0 = (l1 == np.NaN) | (l2 == np.NaN)
print("Lists:")
print(l1)
print(l2)
print()
print("Masks:")
print(mask1)
print(mask0)
```

It prints:

```
Lists:
[nan nan nan  5. nan  6. nan nan  8. nan]
[nan nan nan  5. nan  6. nan  7. nan nan]

Masks:
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True] # not true
[False False False False False False False False False False] # not true
```

I expected:

```
Masks:
[False False False  True False  True False False False False]
[ True  True  True False  True False  True  True  True  True]
```

I made a test and I changed np.NaN to None and this fix a problem with logical operation, but before in my code I calculate items from lists and I have to compare items to value. Then I am getting TypeError:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

How to change all np.NaN to None?

Comment: Don't confuse list and numpy array.  Keep distinction clear in your mind and writing.  Also `np.nan` is a special float value with unique equality properties.  `None` is a unique python object. Pay attention to the `dtype` if your array has either.  And, the string 'nan' is also different.

Comment: Yes, I should pay attention for this difference. Perhaps i tried rewrite pice of code from pandas to numpy.  Now I am wondering that comparation to np.NaN was a programming trick or just my fail. Comparation float or int to  np.NaN is always False.

Comment: pandas has its own nan/none/na testing tools

Comment: `None <4` would produce the last error.  You didn't show exactly how you replaced and compared, but there isn't much you do with `None`..  `None` isn't a number.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot use == and != on np.nan values
nan is not equal to nan

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true) some deep explanation

you have to introduce [np.isnan()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) in the algorithm

```
mask1 = (~np.isnan(l1)) & (~np.isnan(l2))
mask0 = (np.isnan(l1)) | (np.isnan(l2))
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked. Is working. I am wondering Which method is faster. Glauco VS @AkashDataScience. In my first steps I prefer your solution because after few months I will know what is going on. AkashDataScience's solution is also intriguing. Plus for you for link to deep explanation.

Comment: Is that true if I say that we can calculate mask1 as mask1 = (~np.isnan(l1)) & (~np.isnan(l2)) and mask0 as mask0 = ~maks1? If @AkashDataScience did it in this way, here it should work.

Comment: logically are the same, right

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simple.

```
mask1 = l1==l2 
mask2 = ~mask1
```

Comment: I see that bool's algebra is working on a list comparation.  But is that possible to return bool mask for all  logical operation? I see here that you show me something like logical AND for two lists and logical NAND for two lists. Have you solution for  OR operation, NOR operation, EX-OR operation, EX-NOR operation on two lists?

Answer (score 0):

Let's explore the alternatives in more detail

Your array (`l2` similar)

```
In [18]: l1
Out[18]: array([nan, nan, nan,  5., nan,  6., nan, nan,  8., nan])

In [19]: l1.dtype
Out[19]: dtype('float64')
```

Using the `isnan` test:

```
In [20]: np.isnan(l1)
Out[20]: 
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
        True])
```

and combineing them:

```
In [21]: np.isnan(l1)|np.isnan(l2)
Out[21]: 
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```

since `nan` propagate, we could test after

```
In [25]: l1+l2
Out[25]: array([nan, nan, nan, 10., nan, 12., nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

`l1==l2` is the equivalent of testing `l1-l2` for 0s.

```
In [27]: l1-l2
Out[27]: array([nan, nan, nan,  0., nan,  0., nan, nan, nan, nan])

In [28]: l1==l2
Out[28]: 
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False])
```

I could run some `timeit` tests, but for such small arrays they won't tell us a lot.  `np.isnan` is a numpy compiled function and fast enough.

The unique thing about `nan` is that it never equals itself.  Hense your true or false arrays.

```
In [36]: l1==np.nan
Out[36]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

Making your arrays with `None`, makes a object dtype (not float)

```
In [38]: l11
Out[38]: array([None, None, None, 5, None, 6, None, None, 8, None], dtype=object)
```

`None` is different that there is only one `None`, so `is/==` is true, but size comparisons are meaningless

```
In [51]: None is None
Out[51]: True

In [52]: None==None
Out[52]: True

In [53]: None==3
Out[53]: False

In [54]: None<3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[54], line 1
----> 1 None<3

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

`np.isnan` can't be run on this `l11` object dtype array, since it requires floats

I believe `pandas` has some broader tests thatn `np.isnan` but I don't have that installed on this computer.